# Wordreference Forum - comparison

Tags: discussion

What makes this forum better than and different from the [English forum](http://forum.wordreference.com/forumdisplay.php?f=6) at [forum.wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean besides the abysmal difference in the quality of the answers? Just to illustrate:

**Forum:**

Q: What's the difference between dreamt and dreamed?

A: dunno... mayeb it's an American or British English thing...??????

**English Language and Usage:**

Q: Dreamed vs. Dreamt, Leaped vs. Leapt, Lighted vs. Lit

A: [See here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/dreamed-vs-dreamt-leaped-vs-leapt-lighted-vs-lit/2535#2535)

Comment: To expand on this: it's not like *we* have never had a single totally useless answer on *our* site; it's just that SE allows such answers to be downvoted into oblivion and deleted (even without mod interference). On a traditional forum, useless answers and clueless comments linger there for all eternity and interfere with the rest. If the most accurate answer gets posted on page 72, it stays on page 72. Forever. On SE, it can, and in most cases will, bubble to the very top.

Comment: +1 for an interesting and thought-provoking usage of “abysmal”.

Answer (score 7):

Well, let's see:

- our approach is a hybrid of wiki/digg-reddit/blog/forum unlike many other traditional forums
- we have a reputation system through which trusted users are [granted privileges](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges)
- our moderators are democratically elected (will be soon, anyway)

as described on...

https://english.stackexchange.com/about

But subjectively I don't know if this site is "better" than another site, just different.